# Is there a way to force Mathematica 8 to expand $z^{a+b}$ into $z^a z^b$?

Tags: evaluation

The function `PowerExpand[z^(a+b)]` does not transform  $z^{a+b}$ into $z^a z^b$.

Is there a way to force Mathematica 8 to expand $z^{a+b}$ into $z^a z^b$?

In this case, the particular reason why is because the Mod function does not simplify expressions very well. I end up having to expand the powers by hand.
For example, this expression should simplify to zero,

```
2^(3 + 4 k) + 2^(7 + 8 k) - 81^(1 + k);    
Assuming[Element[k, Integers] && k > 1, FullSimplify[Mod[PowerExpand[%],5]]]
```

> ```
> Mod[4 (2^(1 + 4 k) + 2^(5 + 8 k) + 81^(1 + k)), 5]
> ```

Comment: PowerExpand[(x y)^5] not PowerExpand[(5)^(x+y)]

Comment: The problem is that `z^a z^b` is automatically (re)combined into `z^(a+b)`.  You could try `HoldForm`, if you can get it factored; but it might not do what you want, depending on *why* you want to do this.

Comment: @Michael E2 It might be useful to post that as an answer.

Comment: It seems like it ought to be possible to do this using the `ComplexityFunction` option of `Simplify` (or `FullSimplify`). The `FullForm` of z^(a+b) has `Times`, `Plus`, and `Powers` while the `FullForm` of z^a z^b has `Times` and `Powers`  -- hence it ought to be possible to penalize the `Plus` and so get the latter to appear simpler. Unfortunately, I cannot find a good `ComplexityFunction` for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to the get the output formatted as desired:

```
expr = z^(a + b) /. Power[base_, exp_Plus] :> 
             With[{powers = Power[base, List @@ exp]}, HoldForm[powers] /. List -> Times]
```

But the result is a held expression, which must be released in order to use it in standard evaluation.  When released, it automatically adds the exponents.  (There are internal rules that are applied whenever an expression is evaluated.  As far as I know, there is nothing that can be done about them, except to hold up evaluation.)

```
expr // FullForm
```

> ```
> HoldForm[Times[Power[z, a], Power[z, b]]]
> ```

```
expr // ReleaseHold
```

> ```
> z^(a + b)
> ```

The held expression `expr` does not combine algebraically with other expressions, until it's released.

```
expr/z^a
```

> ```
> z^-a (z^a z^b)
> ```

```
expr/z^a // ReleaseHold
```

> ```
> z^b
> ```

Comment: Thanks, taking apart that expression will be a learning experience.

Comment: You're welcome.  Hint: `Power[z, List @@ (a+b)]` first evaluates to `z^{a, b}`.  Then enter that to see what you get.